# Dynamic memory (heap) usage in AXD(ADS 1.2)

Tags: memory, runtime, arm, ads, axd

I'd like to know the dynamic memory usage of my ARM specific library (C code).

How can I get the information in run-time via ADS/AXD tool?
(or RVDS)
Is there a simple way to get the memory statistics by the SDK?

I have tried so many times searching google,
but couldn't find any useful information for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not a simple solution, but one thing you could try would be to use the $Super$$ and $Sub$$ linker features to instrument the malloc/free calls:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0067d/C4clmmh.html